# Simple Sinatra Sessions Not Working

Tags: sinatra, rack, thin

According to [the Sinatra FAQ](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions), a Sinatra app like this should work:

```
enable :sessions

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/foo' do
    session[:message] = 'Hello World!'
    redirect to('/bar')
  end

  get '/bar' do
$stderr.puts session[:message]
    session[:message]   # => 'Hello World!'
  end
end
```

given a `config.ru` like:

```
require 'sinatra'

require './test.rb' # which contains the above MyApp

run MyApp
```

and invoking it via:

```
thin -R config.ru -p 4567 start
```

While the Sinatra code runs, it is not setting a cookie. You can see this in the **`curl -vL http://localhost:4567/foo`** output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4567 (#0)
> GET /foo HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:4567
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Location: http://localhost:4567/bar
< Content-Length: 0
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Connection: keep-alive
* Server thin is not blacklisted
< Server: thin
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://localhost:4567/bar'
* Found bundle for host localhost: 0x1180760
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host localhost
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4567 (#0)
> GET /bar HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:4567
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 0
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Connection: keep-alive
* Server thin is not blacklisted
< Server: thin
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Plus, the `$stderr.puts session[:message]` is not emitting the message, but rather just a blank line.

Swtiching `enable :sessions` to the following also has no impact:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
                       :domain => 'foo.com',
                       :path => '/',
                       :expire_after => 2592000, # In seconds
                       :secret => 'change_me'
```

This is with `thin` 1.6.3, `rack` 1.6.0, and `sinatra` 1.4.5.

Where am I going wrong? Beyond being woefully short on sleep right now...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `enable :sessions` line inside your app class:

```ruby
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  enable :sessions
  #...
```

With that line where it is now you have enabled sessions for the `Sinatra::Application` app, which is the app that is run when you use the [“classic” style](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Modular%20vs.%20Classic%20Style), but that isn’t run here. You need to enable sessions in your app.

With that change you should see the cookie headers being set, but you will need to use something like `curl -vL -b cookie_file -c cookie_file http://localhost:4567/foo` to see it actually work with `curl` (so that the cookies are stored and resent).

Comment: Actually, just seeing the cookie headers flowing is a vast improvement. Many thanks!